# Picture-inPicture video display problem | Android

Tags: android, exoplayer, picture-in-picture

I am trying to work on picture-in-picture mode with exoplayer integrated

I am able to get picture-in-picture view, but I can't get the full view of video in picture-in-picture mode.

[image]

For Example:
Red one is the video, and when I go into picture-in-picture view, only green part of video is visible.

Here is my code:

```
 @Override
protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
    super.onUserLeaveHint();

    enterPipMode();
}

private void enterPipMode() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N
            && getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_PICTURE_IN_PICTURE)) {            
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
           PictureInPictureParams.Builder builder = new PictureInPictureParams.Builder();

            enterPictureInPictureMode(builder.build());
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                enterPictureInPictureMode();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you used `Rationale` to get aspect ratio of video ?

Answer (score 0):

That's how i have implemented `PictureInPicture` in my app.

```
@Override
protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        if (!isInPictureInPictureMode()) {
            Rational rational = new Rational(250, 150); //you can use VideoView getWidth(),getHeight() here 
            builder.setAspectRatio(rational).build();
            enterPictureInPictureMode(builder.build());
        }
    }
}
```

Then detect if User has minimized the screen

```
@Override
public void onPictureInPictureModeChanged(boolean isInPictureInPictureMode, Configuration newConfig) {
    if (isInPictureInPictureMode) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "in picture in picture mode.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "out of picture in picture mode.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Initialize  `PictureInPitureParam.Builder` in onCreate()

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        builder = new PictureInPictureParams.Builder();
    }
```